# Insert a random gap into a vector

Tags: r, function

I have a protein sequence (for example, a vector `"I" "D" "I" "A" "S"`)

I would like to implement a function to insert a random gap `*` in that sequence.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check out the `Biostrings` package and the function `replaceAt`, you can use `sample` to feed it a random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
f <- function(x) { 
  id <- sample(seq(x), 1)
  c(x[1:id], "*", x[-(1:id)])
}
set.seed(123)
f(c("I", "D", "I", "A", "S"))
# [1] "I" "D" "*" "I" "A" "S"
f(c("I", "D", "I", "A", "S"))
# [1] "I" "D" "I" "A" "*" "S"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
func_insert_at <- function(vec, elements, at){
x <- rep(NA, length(vec)+length(elements));
x[at] <- elements;x[-at] <- vec;x;}

vec <- c("I", "D", "I", "A", "S")
set.seed(23)
func_insert_at(vec, "*", ceiling(runif(1, 0, length(vec))))
# [1] "I" "D" "*" "I" "A" "S"
func_insert_at(vec, "*", ceiling(runif(1, 0, length(vec))))
# [1] "I" "*" "D" "I" "A" "S"
```

The advantage of this function is that `elements` parameter of the function can be of any length (not specifically `1`). For example,

```
elements=c("M", "O", "H")
positions=c(1,3,6)
func_insert_at(vec, elements, positions)
# [1] "M" "I" "O" "D" "I" "H" "A" "S"
```